# onClick does not work after removing "disabled" from (React) button

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom-events, mouseevent

```
const MIN_LENGTH = 6;
class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      emailValid: false,
      passwordValid: false,
      // redirect: false,
    };

    this.handleEmail = this.handleEmail.bind(this);
    this.handlePassword = this.handlePassword.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.handleButton();
  }

  handleEmail(ev) {
    const email = ev.target.value;
    const re = /^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;
    const isValid = re.test(email);
    if (isValid) {
      this.setState({ emailValid: true, email });
    } else {
      this.setState({ emailValid: false, email: '' });
    }
  }

  handlePassword(ev) {
    const size = ev.target.value.length;
    if (size >= MIN_LENGTH) {
      this.setState({ passwordValid: true, password: ev.target.value });
    } else {
      this.setState({ passwordValid: false, password: '' });
    }
  }

  handleButton() {
    const { emailValid, passwordValid } = this.state;
    const btn = document.getElementById('btnLogin');
    if (emailValid && passwordValid) {
      btn.disabled = false;
    } else {
      btn.disabled = true;
    }
  }

  handleClick(ev) {
    console.log(ev);
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log('click!');
  }

  render() {
    const { email, password, emailValid, passwordValid } = this.state;
    if (emailValid && passwordValid) {
      console.log(`Email:${email}\nSenha:${password}`);
    }
    return (
      <section>
        <label htmlFor="email-input">
          Email
          <input type="email" data-testid="email-input" onChange={ this.handleEmail } />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="password-input">
          Password
          <input
            type="password"
            data-testid="password-input"
            onChange={ this.handlePassword }
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <button
          type="button"
          id="btnLogin"
          onClick={ this.handleClick }
          disabled
        >
          Login
        </button>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

The code above is a React component that will login my application. It is important to say that the validations are working perfectly, the button is only enabled when everything goes well, however when clicking the button nothing happens.The function "handleEmail" has the role of verifying via regex the validity of the email, and the email is only changed in the component state when it is valid. The "handlePassword" function only checks if the password entered is greater than or equal to 6. I'm storing this information in the component's state but the idea is to save this data in a global state in the future using "Redux". My only problem for now is the bug with the button's onClick.

Comment: Try to remove the property "disabled" completely, does this what you expect? For JSX "disabled" is afaik the same as "disabled={true}".

Comment: If you look closely, in the "handleButton" function this is exactly what I do, the button is enabled, but when you click, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not access the dom elements from the React directly, because react controls each component using js and does not see that you have changed the property in the html. You shouldn't do things like this one:

```
handleButton() {
    const { emailValid, passwordValid } = this.state;
    const btn = document.getElementById('btnLogin');
    if (emailValid && passwordValid) {
        btn.disabled = false;
    } else {
        btn.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

You should add the property to the state, that stores the status of the button. Aka, add `disabled` boolean property and change it in the handler.

Your button gonna look like:

```
<button ... disabled={this.state.buttonDisabled} />
```

Your handleButton gonna look like this:

```
handleButton() {
    const { emailValid, passwordValid } = this.state;
    this.setState({
        buttonDisabled: !(emailValid && passwordValid)
    });
}
```

Comment: I think I would: buttonDisabled: !(emailValid && passwordValid), right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. My mistake